# jquery IE8 $(document).ready "object expected" error

Tags: jquery, object, internet-explorer-8, object-expected

I'm having a problem with IE8 throwing an "object expected" error when loading a page with the jquery command `$(document).ready()`.  I've gone through all the other posts I can find here on SO, and none of the solutions seem to work.

To troubleshoot, I created the following html, which runs fine in Firefox and Chrome, but produces an "object expected" error at the `$(document).ready` line. So far:

1. I've confirmed it is reaching the google jquery file - and tried referencing a local jquery.js file - same result.
2. Tried placing the script in the `<head>` (I've included it in the body to recreate the situation on the site I'm developing on)
3. I've also tried this with `jQuery(document)` instead of `$` - same result
4. Tried including: `var $j=jQuery.noConflict();` and including `$j(document)`, getting a 'jQuery is undefined' error on the `$j` declaration.

What am I missing?  ANY help is appreciated!  Thanks!

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
    alert("WORKING!");
    });

</script>

<div id="test">
</div>
</body></html>
```

Comment: This isn't your problem, but just want to mention that `$(function(){ ... })` is shorthand for `$(document).ready(function(){ ... });`.

Comment: This has to do with the computer that is running IE8 and corrupted .dll files. You can most likely use another computer to run it and it will work.

Comment: @Esailija: I thought IE 8 *was* a corrupted dll file. `/snark`

Comment: Hmm.. works in Firefox and chrome, so the link should be good.  Unless IE is not... AHHH!  The script link needs to be type="text/javascript".  Works now... Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Mate, check your two script tags. One says `type="application/javascript"`, the other says `type="text/javascript"`.

Change the first one to `type="text/javascript"` and it will work fine.

Comment: Even if that script tag is ignored, it wouldn't give this error. It would say something like `$ is undefined` or whatever. In my IE8: `"The value of the property '$' is null or undefined, not a Function object"`

Comment: Told ya! :) Tested and replicated this in jsfiddle.

Comment: What OS/IE8 exact version? I copypasted his code verbatim and get the error I mentioned :P

Comment: Win7 Enterprise + IE8 8.0.7601.17514

Comment: @Esailija IE doesn't usually recognize application/javascript as javascript.

Comment: @KevinB yeah I know, I use the trick in templates because script tags with type defined but incorrectly are ignored.

Answer (score 4):

Had the same problem. I fixed this by struggling hard for some time and tried a bunch of thinks that did'nt work. 
But this work:)

Check you jquery script tag. If it contains the type="text/javascript" like this

```
<script  type="text/javascript" src="~/scripts/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
```

then replace the "text/javascript" with only "javascript"

```
<script type="javascript" src="~/scripts/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
```

Really vierd behaviour but it works. If anyone has a good explanation then please post an answer to this.

NB! This works only for IE8, not for Chrome or Firefox !

Answer (score 2):

Just encountered this error as well.

The problem on my part was pretty dumb: I ran the Internet Explorer in a Virtual Machine. This machine didn't have access to the Internet but only to the host system where I had the webserver running. 
Therefore, the external script references could not be resolved of course.

Answer (score 0):

The thing helped me replacing

```
type="text/javascript"
```

into

```
language="javascript"
```