# Change element color within div with javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I have some links within a div:

```
<div class="sidebar" id="sidebar">

  <ul>
    <li><a href="a.php">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="b.php">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="c.php">Link 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I load a stylesheet that has this:

```
.sidebar a {
    text-decoration: none;
            font-weight:normal;
}
.sidebar a:hover {
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: underline;
                font-weight:bold;
}
```

This stylesheet is used on multiple pages.  On some, I want to change the color of the "a" elements.  Based on my research, I have tried this jquery to change the color of the "a" elements:

```
$("div.sidebar a").css({color : "#000000"});
```

But when I do this, I get this error: Object expected.

Holy cow, what in the world am I missing?

Comment: Your code works exactly as you expect... http://jsfiddle.net/3bRvP/

Comment: Yeah, the problem is somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure jquery is loading on the pages where you get the `Object expected` error?

Looks like its working here. 
http://jsbin.com/ekinuy/1/edit

Also note: 
[jquery IE8 $(document).ready "object expected" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11869093/jquery-ie8-document-ready-object-expected-error)

Comment: I had jquery in the page, with a freakin typo.  Thanks for the thought and everyone's responses!

Answer (score 0):

Working here: http://jsfiddle.net/8dk9F/

```
$(".sidebar a").css("color", "red");
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this it should work for you.  Some browsers are a little more finicky than others.

```
$('div.sidebar a').css({"color" : "#ccc"});
```

Comment: If any support difference exists between these color formats, I would expect far more support for the 6 character format. But wither way this wouldn't solve the problem being described.